# Google Chrome app file opened is not always in front, receiving focus

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome, focus

On Windows Vista, I'm launching files associated with a Google Chrome "Application Shortcut" app by double-clicking them. While they will always open this way, they will *sometimes* not receive focus -- i.e. they sit in the task bar quietly but don't actually show in front on the screen (until I click on the app in the task bar again).

Does anyone know how I can force the just-opened app to receive focus?

The app being opened actually contains a web app I can customize, so I also have access to performing JavaScript commands post-startup. For background information, [here is the regedit file](http://blogoscoped.com/temp/associate-filetype-sample.reg) I originally used to create the file association. Might well be this is a Google Chrome internal issue... apps I open with other editors get their focus alright, AFAIK. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
WinWaitActive, ,Google Chrome
WinActivate
```

you can change the title to something closer to your app to avoid conflict with other chrome windows.

Comment: Thanks. Would I still be able to call Google Chrome with several parameters, which is needed? (As shown in the linked reg file)

Comment: As long as you specify part of the window title yes

Comment: I fixed your link. :)

Comment: @music Thank you, I must have been in a hurry :)